# Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server 2012 which works, but I have changed the order (Id, Slug, CategoryName) to (Id, CategoryName, Slug) in order to match the returned data and column names and now I get this error:

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "CategoryName" of recursive query "categoryPath"

This is the query:

```
WITH categoryPath(Id, CategoryName, Slug)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id, CategoryName, Slug 
    FROM Categories
    WHERE ParentCategoryId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Categories.Id,
        CAST(categoryPath.CategoryName + ' / ' + categories.CategoryName AS NVARCHAR(150)),
        categories.Slug
    FROM Categories
    JOIN categoryPath ON Categories.ParentCategoryId = categoryPath.Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM [ItemCategories]
JOIN categoryPath ON [ItemCategories].CategoryId = categoryPath.Id 
WHERE [ItemCategories].StockId = '5'
```

Comment: What is the datatype of categories.Slug?

Comment: I meant CategoryName, not Slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I get this error, I just cast galore and it soon works:

```
WITH categoryPath(Id, CategoryName, Slug) AS (
      SELECT Id, cast(CategoryName as nvarchar(150)), cast(Slug as nvarchar(150))
      FROM Categories
      WHERE ParentCategoryId IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Categories.Id,
             CAST(categoryPath.CategoryName + ' / ' + categories.CategoryName AS NVARCHAR(150)),
             CAST(categories.Slug as nvarchar(150))
      FROM Categories JOIN
           categoryPath
           ON Categories.ParentCategoryId=categoryPath.Id
     )
. . .
```

Comment: now I get a different error: Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "CategoryName" of recursive query "categoryPath".

Comment: @MarioM . . . I think this happens because the length of the string changes after string concatenation, and recursive CTEs even care about the length.  I never investigated in great detail because it is pretty easy to work around.

Comment: Thanks! It was very strange to get that error only after changing the column orders.